# What is the best way of checking for my android application updates?

Tags: android, android-studio

I have an android application created in android studio.

I want to check daily whether an update is available for my app or not. if yes, then notify user to download and install the update.

---

1. it should send a request to my server to check for the newest version(e.g. https://my-site.com/get-app-info/newest-version)
2. then it compares the version, if the version which is gotten from server was greater than current app version -> send a notification to user and ask them to update it

---

- it should run in background once a day
- at the time, device should be connected to internet

---

I searched a lot and I found many answers such as using these:

- broadcast receiver
- work manager
- alarm manager
- services

I faced some problems for example:

- broadcast receiver with `connectivity change` is deprecated in android 7
- a service is not a good choice, because it is always running
- and many more...

I want to know which one best suits my job. and how to do it.
thanks in advance.

Comment: Is this application in the app store or do they manually install it and manually install updates?

Comment: @tyczj no they should manually install updates

Comment: A lot of trouble there then, users have press a notification to download the file and then install it from the file explorer, seems easy but for users tha's a lot of trouble. Work manager with retrofit worked for me.

Comment: @javdromero how about volley? is it good for this job?

Comment: It is, you didn't say much about what kind of request are you going to use, like rest, post, get or any other, but both libraries work, you should check the better one depending on what you are using

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [WorkManager](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager) you can set it to run once a day and even only run when there is an internet connection.

In the work manager you would make a the call to check your app version then show a notification if there is an update.

Create the work manager somewhat like this

```
val constraints = Constraints.Builder().setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED).build()
val dailyBuilder = PeriodicWorkRequestBuilder<DailyMaintenanceWorker>(1, TimeUnit.DAYS).setConstraints(constraints) .build()
WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueueUniquePeriodicWork("DailyMaintenanceWorker", ExistingPeriodicWorkPolicy.KEEP, dailyBuilder)
```

Comment: ok thanks then, but could you please also give an example of how to register this work manager?

Comment: I linked the work manager docs in my answer. https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/basics

Comment: and then just one more little question … should I run this code in my activity? then how to ensure that this code executes one time just after installation? or a way to register this worker in manifest?

Comment: Just start it in your application class then you know that anytime the app is started it either creates the work or keeps the one that is currently created. One thing to be aware of though is that some manufacturers have been known to break how work manager works where if your app is force quit or cleared from the recent's list then work manager wont start your work. There is nothing you can do about that unfortunately.

Comment: you can see what manufacturers are the worst offenders https://dontkillmyapp.com/